# Extracting Value In Between Quotes - Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, xml, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a request ID for running load testing on J Meter that I need to use for the subsequent HTTP requests. I'm using the regular expression extractor to do this.

I've been trying for hours and hours to extract the value inside single quotations and have not had any success. The response looks similar to this.

RequestDateTime='2/12/2017 7:19:49 AM' RequestID='1234567' Client="14232" etc...

I want the exact numbers with no quotations around it. The value should be 1234567

I've tried using RequestID='(.*?)' but it gives the entire string whereas I just want the value inside.

Comment: your regex should be working correctly. So could you please provide more details on how you specify RegEx, which elements you are using etc

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression `RequestID='(\d+)`
Template $1$ 
Match 1

Answer (score 0):

Looking into "RegExp" Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener your regular expression itself is fine:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Tester]

So my expectation is that your Regular Expression Extractor configuration is not correct, you should get expected value if use something like:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `RequestID`
- Regular Expression: `RequestID='(.*?)'`
- Template: `$1$`

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Configuration]

You should be able to refer the extracted value as `${RequestID}` later on. Extracted JMeter Variable(s) can be visualised  using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

[image: JMeter Debug Sampler Show Variables]

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about JMeter tests troubleshooting techniques.

Answer (score 0):

So the following regular expression should do the trick: `'(\d*)'`
Then Insert a Debug Sampler into your thread so you can see the reference name. The variable you are looking for will have the following name: *referencename_g0*

The `_g0` represents the first group that was matched. If the expression matches other chars in your response, simply use the variable with the correct group number. (e.g _g1 or _g2, etc).

Hope this helps!