# How to create regular expression to get a string in between ""

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to create a regular expression to extract A-ticket from Json ( A value which exists after the A-ticket.I need the value without "". Then I need to pass the key into respective requests in Jmeter.

{"test","test2","A-ticket":"4523963f-6c9a-4d6a-b862-f35db64fc536","amr":["password"]}

I would expect
4523963f-6c9a-4d6a-b862-f35db64fc536 (I don't need A-ticket and "". Only need the value)

This is the regular expression which I created.But this is not working in Jmeter because it doesn't support look behind.

(?<=A-ticket”:“).[^”]*

Comment: You do not need a lookbehind. Use `"A-ticket":"([^"]+)` with `$1$` template.  A better idea is to use JSON Extractor.

Comment: I don't know what programming language you are using, but most of this times in cases like this string, you can put it inside a function where is returns an `Object` or `Array` version of you string. So than you would just say: `object->amr` and it would return `["password"]`. You should look this up corresponding to your programming language.

Comment: Also, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147275/extracting-value-in-between-quotes-regular-expressions), too.